# Timer Loop crashes sporadically after returning from the background

Tags: iphone, ios6

I'm having a consistent problem in my latest app release.  I have a timer that runs in the AppDelegate that calls a function every 30 seconds to load a new advertisement. I'm thinking it's the culprit in this crash.  Using Crittercism, I've had over 20 crashes for 13 users.  Users are mostly using IOS 6 or some variation of it.  Here is the log that it's giving me:

SEGV_ACCERR

0   libobjc.A.dylib        0x3acd25b0 objc_msgSend + 16

1   Foundation             0x3394b277 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 451

2   CoreFoundation         0x330125df **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 15

3   CoreFoundation         0x33012291 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 273

4   CoreFoundation         0x33010f01 __CFRunLoopRun + 1233

5   CoreFoundation         0x32f83ebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357

6   CoreFoundation         0x32f83d49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105

7   GraphicsServices       0x36b452eb GSEventRunModal + 75

8   UIKit                  0x34e99301 UIApplicationMain + 1121

9   AutoScene              0x000031b7 main (main.m:7)

My timer is:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30 target:self selector:@selector(resetAdTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

I dont know if it's the same problem, but I've experienced times where I return to the app from the background and it just hangs.. It seems to hang for 30 seconds too which leads me to believe it's the timer code.

Is this a poor way of managing the ad fetching?  Does the timer code screw up when it goes into the background for a long time?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You should invalidate the timer in appWillResignActive and create it again in appWillBecome active.  [From the docs...](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

> You should use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and
>   throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to
>   pause the game. An application in the inactive state should do minimal
>   work while it waits to transition to either the active or background
>   state.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this for **Swift 4.2**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appWillResignActive), name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appBecomesActive), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
}


@objc func appWillResignActive() {
    //to background
}

@objc func appBecomesActive() {
    //to front
}
```

Don't forget to remove the observers.

```
    notificationCenter.removeObserver(self, name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
    notificationCenter.removeObserver(self, name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
```

Inspired from here https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-detect-when-your-app-moves-to-the-background